# How to add vertical scrollbar to sliding tab?

Tags: jquery, css, scrollbar, overflow, slidingmenu

I have a sliding tab implementation on http://thehungrygeek.com/ - i.e. the sliding drawer on the right side of the screen.

How do I add a vertical scrollbar to the sliding drawer using CSS that only appears when the visitor's display screen height is too small such that it cuts off part of the sliding drawer?

I have tried the following CSS code:

```
#tab_slide {
overflow-x: auto;
overflow-y: scroll
height:auto;       // styles added by tab-slide plugin which I am using
top:5%;            // ---- || ----
right: -303px;     // ---- || ----
width: 300px;      // ---- || ----
}
```

With that code implementation, there is a vertical scroll bar but it does not scroll when the display height is smaller than the tab slide.

How do I get a workable vertical scrollbar that only appears when the tab slide can't fit the available display?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please can you write code here then external link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got you right then changing these lines from,

```
#tab_slide {
 overflow-x: auto;
 overflow-y: scroll
 height:auto;       // styles added by tab-slide plugin which I am using
 top:5%;            // ---- || ----
 right: -303px;     // ---- || ----
 width: 300px;      // ---- || ----
}
```

To :

```
#tab_slide {
overflow-x: auto;
overflow-y: scroll
height:100%;         // **note this lines
overflow-y : auto;    // **note this lines
top:5%;            
right: -303px;     
width: 300px;      
}
```

If the styles are added by plugin you might want to add '!important' to style values.

Comment: thanks for this, works like a charm... however `height:100%` makes the slide tab extend down the whole screen though, is there a way to achieve what I want without this cosmetic change?

Comment: If you want the slide tab /drawer to be of fixed height... try height in pixels.I am not sure what exactly what you want.

Comment: I tried setting height in pixels right at the start, but when that is done, the vertical scrollbar doesn't appear on overflow.

Comment: Can you elaborate this "_makes the slide tab extend down the whole screen though_ " ...please.

Comment: On default settings, the tab is around 820px in height. When `height:100%` is set, the tab stretches down to the full screen.

If you use Chrome inspect or firebug, you can uncheck the `height:100% !important` element and see how it looks normally.

Comment: Can you try reducing height to somewhere around 80%..or so as it suits you.

Comment: When I do that, a horizontal scrollbar appears and there's also a problem as it will render sub-optimally on different resolutions.

Comment: I don't know  exactly how the code is structured, but I can advice to use @media for resolution issue(set height for different media sizes/ resolutions) and as for horizontal scroll bar ..set overflow-x = hidden;

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@media all and (max-height:400px){
  #tab_slide{
     overflow-x: auto;
     overflow-y: scroll;
  }
}
```

When the screen height is changed to `400px`, a scroll bar will appear. You can change the `max-height` to whatever size you want.